# pass pl/sql record as arguement to procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to pass pl/sql record type to a procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKGDeleteNumber
AS
 PROCEDURE deleteNumber (
    list_of_numbers  IN List_Numbers
 )
 IS
   i_write VARCHAR2(5);
 BEGIN
   --do something
 END deleteNumber;

END PKGDeleteNumber;
/
```

In this procedure `deleteNumber` I have used `List_Numbers`, which is a record type. The package declaration for the same is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKGDeleteNumber
AS
   TYPE List_Numbers IS RECORD (
     IID NUMBER
   );
  TYPE list_of_numbers IS TABLE OF List_Numbers;
  PROCEDURE deleteNumber (
    list_of_numbers  IN List_Numbers
  );
END PKGDeleteNumber;
```

I have to execute the procedure `deleteNumber` passing a list of values. I inserted numbers in `temp_test` table, then using a cursor U fetched the data from it :

```
   SELECT *
     BULK COLLECT INTO test1
     FROM temp_test;
```

Now, to call the procedure I am using

```
execute immediate  'begin PKGDELETENUMBER.DELETENUMBER(:1); end;' 
  using test1;
```

I have tried many other things as well(`for loop`, `dbms_binding`, etc). How do I pass a pl/sql record type as argument to the procedure?

EDIT:

Basically, I want to pass a list of numbers, using native dynamic sql only...

adding the table temp_test defn (no index or constraint):

```
create table test_temp ( 
   IID number
);
```

and then inserted 1,2,3,4,5 using normal `insert` statements.

For this solution,

```
In a package testproc
CREATE TYPE num_tab_t IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_dyn_proc_test (p_num_array IN num_tab_t) AS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(p_num_array.COUNT);
END;
/
```

this is called from sql prompt/toad
    DECLARE
      v_tab testproc.num_tab_t := testproc.num_tab_t(1, 10);
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN testproc.my_dyn_proc_test(:1); END;' USING v_tab;
    END;

this will not work.This shows error.I am not at my workstation so am not able to reproduce the issue now.

Comment: You don't show the definition of test1, and you getting an error?  Please show it.

Comment: it is a simple table with 5 numbers in it...will put the defination

Comment: did you tried collections?

Comment: Why do you want to use native dynamic SQL (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) for this?

Comment: there is some project requirement becoz of which i have to use dynamic sql only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `RECORD` types in `USING` clause of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement. If you just want to pass a list of numbers, why don't you just use a variable of `TABLE OF NUMBER` type? Check below example:

```
CREATE TYPE num_tab_t IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_dyn_proc_test (p_num_array IN num_tab_t) AS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(p_num_array.COUNT);
END;
/

DECLARE
  v_tab num_tab_t := num_tab_t(1, 10);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN my_dyn_proc_test(:1); END;' USING v_tab;
END;
```

Output:

```
2
```

---

**Edit**

Try this:

```
CREATE TYPE num_tab_t IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE testproc AS
  PROCEDURE my_dyn_proc_test (p_num_array IN num_tab_t);
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY testproc AS
  PROCEDURE my_dyn_proc_test (p_num_array IN num_tab_t) AS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(p_num_array.COUNT);
  END;
END;
/

DECLARE
  v_tab num_tab_t := num_tab_t(1, 10);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN testproc.my_dyn_proc_test(:1); END;' USING v_tab;
END;
```

Comment: this is not working when i am using different packages.do you have a solution for that as well?

Comment: @subodh1989 What do you mean? It is a general solution, you have to use the `num_tab_t` type in every procedure/function for each parameter that is supposed to be an array of numbers. Please edit your question to show what you mean that it doesn't work for other packages.

Comment: @subodh1989 Check my edited answer. Basically, the `num_tab_t` type must be declared outside of the package, as shown in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Use an object type.  object types are visible to all packages